# How to seperate schema and table in the raw query string in Sequelize Migration

Tags: sequelize.js, sequelize-cli

I'm trying to create a table using Sequelize migrations with a foreign key reference to a table in a seperate schema in my database. The issue appears to be that sequelize builds the query with the foreign key reference as

```
ALTER TABLE `budgets` 
ADD CONSTRAINT `deliverableId_fkey` 
FOREIGN KEY (`deliverableId`) REFERENCES `central.deliverables` (`deliverableid`) 
ON UPDATE CASCADE ON DELETE CASCADE;
```

which produces the error `ERROR: Failed to open the referenced table 'central.deliverables'`.

Seperating the string after "REFERENCES" to split the schema and table is then successful when ran in mysql cli.

```
ALTER TABLE `budgets` 
ADD CONSTRAINT `deliverableId_fkey` 
FOREIGN KEY (`deliverableId`) REFERENCES `central`.`deliverables` (`deliverableid`) 
ON UPDATE CASCADE ON DELETE CASCADE;
```

This same error occurs when in the `createTable` method when ran as such:

```
...},
  deliverableId: {
    type: Sequelize.DataTypes.INTEGER,
    allowNull: true,
    references: {
      model: {
        tableName: "deliverables",
        schema: "central",
      },
      key: "deliverableid",
    },
  },
```

so I'm wondering what I can do in sequelize to get the correct MySQL query

Comment: The syntax looks ok for me. Are you sure that the error is the exact same one and you don't have other `createTable` calls in the same migration file?

Comment: @Anatoly I opened a issue in git and it appears to be lack of support for schemas in sequelize 6. So I was able to use raw query to get the same functionality. Appears there is no "sequelize" syntax that can get same functionality